Equations Below Rotated Forest
I created the following graph:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}


\begin{document}

\Rotatebox{90}{
\small
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily,
    line width=1pt,
    edge={line width=1pt},
    draw,
    align=left,
  },
  s sep+=20pt,
  [Strong Diabatic Heating,drop shadow,
  fill=white
    [Synoptic-Scale Dynamics 
     [Thermodynamic \\ Equation
     [(1)]
     ]
     [PV Equation
     [(2)]
     ]
     [Continuity \\ Equation
          [(3)]
     [(4)]
     ]
     [Hor. Momentum \\ Equation
     [(5)]
     ]
     [Hydrostatic Balance \\ Equation
     [(6)]
     ]
    ]
    [Mesoscale Dynamics
     [Thermodynamic\\ Equation
        [(7)]
        [(8)]
     ]
     [Vorticity\\ Equation
     [(9)]
     ]
     [Continuity \\ Equation
        [(10)]
        [(11)]
    ]
    [Hydrostatic Balance \\ Equation
    [(12)]
    ]
    [Mesoscale Horizontal \\Divergence Equation
    [(13)]
    ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
}

\end{document}


I would like to add a list of equations next to the forest. They would ideally also be rotated. Do you know if that is possible (and if so, how? Could I use minipages)?

The tree is visibly too large for your page. Do you want the equations below? I.e. rotated but below?

How is this different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718466/? Could you explain why the answers there won't work?

As I explained in my answer there, you can rotate the tree using e.g. sidewaysfigure from the rotating package and you can include the equations, too. Or you can add them to the box beneath the tree. But you have the problem that your tree is simply too wide. When I compile your code, the first page is empty because LaTeX pushes the box to another page in hopes of making it fit. When that doesn't work, it outputs it anyway rather than discard it. In your real document, this is liable to cause trouble. You either make it smaller or you lie to TeX about how big it is.

Or are you using A4?

I've added a couple of other options to my answer to your earlier question about this so that they are all together.
