How to Add a Rotated Caption to Rotated Forest
I generated the following graph:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sideways}
        \parbox{\textheight}{%
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
        forked edges,
        for tree={
          line width=1pt,
          edge+={line width=1pt},
          draw,
          align=left,
          tier/.option=level,
        },
        s sep'+=10pt,
        [\large{Forest}, fill=white
          [A.
          [(1)]
          ]
          [B.
          [(2)]
          ]
          [C.
                [(3)]
          [(4)]
          ]
          [D.
          [(5)]
          ]
          [E.
          [(6)]
          ]
        ]
        \end{forest}}
    \end{sideways}
\end{document}

How can I add a rotated caption? I can't seem to place it inside \sideways

What should the caption say? "Figure xx: "?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz figure number and caption title. Similar to the standard figure caption

Please note that you are supposed to attribute code you take from this site with a link. This makes it a whole lot easier for people trying to help you because they can see the context of what you're trying to do. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718466/ (cc @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz)

@cfr Argh! Why don't users say where the code is from?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Rhetorical, I hope!

@cfr Your rhetoric detector works perfectly :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm sorry! Noted!

You could use a sidewaysfigure:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
        forked edges,
        for tree={
          line width=1pt,
          edge+={line width=1pt},
          draw,
          align=left,
          tier/.option=level,
        },
        s sep'+=10pt,
        [\large{Forest}, fill=white
          [A.
          [(1)]
          ]
          [B.
          [(2)]
          ]
          [C.
                [(3)]
          [(4)]
          ]
          [D.
          [(5)]
          ]
          [E.
          [(6)]
          ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
        \caption{some caption}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}


Or use the \captionof macro from the caption package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sideways}
        \parbox{\textheight}{%
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
        forked edges,
        for tree={
          line width=1pt,
          edge+={line width=1pt},
          draw,
          align=left,
          tier/.option=level,
        },
        s sep'+=10pt,
        [\large{Forest}, fill=white
          [A.
          [(1)]
          ]
          [B.
          [(2)]
          ]
          [C.
                [(3)]
          [(4)]
          ]
          [D.
          [(5)]
          ]
          [E.
          [(6)]
          ]
        ]
        \end{forest}%
        \captionof{figure}{some caption}%
        }
    \end{sideways}
\end{document}



great, many thanks!

@s28 I appreciate you didn't know you could use \caption inside sidewaysfigure, but are you aware you can find documentation when an answer tells you which package provides an environment or command? So if you wanted, say, the figure to be rotated in the other direction, you could just look at that rather than needing to ask another question and wait for an answer?
